# What does "Experience" refer to in the Chrome developer tools performance window?

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, profiler

I'm trying to debug my canvas game's performance and I received this as a result after running it for 10 seconds while profiling with Chrome's performance profiler:

[image]

What is Experience? I don't think I've seen it before. Is it new?

I tried expanding it in the "Bottom-Up View" but it mostly just seems like things like events and timers? Not sure why it is taking up so much CPU time considering it's just some trivial things like handling mouse events.